# Powershell diplay information once folder size has been calculated

Tags: powershell

I am writing an Powershell Script/App which allows Domain Users logging on  to be able to delete their Profile Application Data Setting folders in order to fix applications that don't load (usually caused by corrupt/missing data in their AppData folder).

I have written the app, it works but there is a problem. It takes too long to load as the Script displays a message to the user notifying them if their profile size quota has exceeded (as the company has quota'd AppData folders for each user). To do this it needs to calculate their profile app data folders size using the following code, it does this on startup:

```
Get-ChildItem $GetPath -recurse -ea silentlycontinue | Measure-Object -property length -sum
```

I don't want to do this on startup, I want to load the GUI first with a message at the top saying 'Calculating Profile Size...' and then calculate the profile size on the fly and return results once it has finished calculating, any ideas how to do this if at all possible. I have looked at using Start-Job to start calculating the profile size and then Recieve-Job to get the results but can't seem to work out how to display a message on the Powershell GUI (form) according to the results and to check if the job has finished.

Any pointers or help?

Comment: "on startup" - as in when the machine starts/windows boot or at login time?

Comment: No this is a like a program that users click to launch from their windows desktop, there is an icon on the desktop which launches the GUI (Powershell form) ...

Comment: So basically I want to display the form with a list of all their apps and the buttons which allows them to delete appdata folders but at the same time give them a message that their profile size is  being calculated and then display their profile size to them once the calculation has been done ...Sorry if I am not being explicit...My first post and all ...

Comment: @user1694244 Use a [background job](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847783.aspx) or a separate runspace to calculate the size in the background

Comment: Yes thanks I managed to solve my issue by starting a background job when the GUI is loaded (using the following onload gui event in powershell):

$objForm.Add_Shown
({

Start-Job -Name CalculateProfileSize -ScriptBlock {Write-Output (Get-ChildItem $env:APPDATA -recurse -ea silentlycontinue | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum}

Wait-Job -Name CalculateProfileSize 
$ProfileSize = Receive-Job -Name CalculateProfileSize
$ProfileSizeTotal = "{0:N2}" -f ($ProfileSize / 1.00MB) + " MB"
$outputBox.Text="$ProfileSizeTotal Profile Size" 
Get-Job -Name CalculateProfileSize | Remove-Job  
  
   })